# Vimeo — get videos without tag

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Is there any way to get all the videos from Vimeo that don't contain a tag?

E.g. `/videos?tag_not=excluded` or something similar.

The query parameter just called [query](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#search_videos) is a string, and it appears to search free text in the title and/or description.

There is documentation for getting [videos with a specific tag](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos_with_tag), but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Not available, this is pretty common with most API's. You can however from a programmatic approach loop through the responses and just return results that have no tags as a workaround.